# class managing objects of other class with container

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to implement two classes.

One should contain an Employee with no methods, just constructor.

Second one should have `std::vector` container in with all the Employers made inside it, and few methods to manipulate those objects for example to add new employee or change his id.

After many attempts with errors im stuck and i dont know how to pass created employees to container in second class. I dont even know how the HR class should look like (its constructor should only have container?) and how it can make this container of Employee class objects.

First class is *Employee.h*, *Employee.cpp* and second is *HR.h*, *HR.cpp*

Here is my *Employee.h*

```
#include <iostream>
class Employee {
    public:
        std::string id;
        std::string name;
        std::string surname;
        std::string departmentId;
        std::string position;

        Employee(std::string id, std::string name, std::string surname, std::string departmentId, std::string position);
        ~Employee();
    };
```

*Employee.cpp*

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

Employee::Employee(std::string xid, std::string xname, std::string xsurname, std::string xdepartmentId, std::string xposition) : id (std::move(xid)), name (std::move(xname)), surname (std::move(xsurname)), departmentId (std::move(xdepartmentId)), position (std::move(xposition))
{
    std::cout << "constructor of worker"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "id:" + this->id + "  name:" + this->name + "  surname:" + this-> surname + "  department:" + this->departmentId + "  position:" + this->position << std::endl;
};

Employee::~Employee()
{
    std::cout << "destructor"<< std::endl;
};
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Employee.h"
#include "HR.h"
int main() {
    Employee first("2","John","Smith","1","c++ developer");
    Employee second("3","Steven","McDonald","2","administrator");
    Employee third("4","Mark","Johnson","1","c++ developer");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Should i place this push_back in Employee constructor and throw it somehow to HR class everytime new employee is created?

I'm really stuck right here.

EDIT: *HR.h* code - it's almost nothing there. std::vector is now created by method of HR. I dont know how HR constructor should look like and how can it implement objects from Employee class to vector container.

*HR.h*

```
#include "Employee.h"
#include <vector>

class HR {

public:

void addEmp(Employee);

HR();
~HR();
};
```

*HR.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "HR.h"
HR::HR()
{
    std::cout << "constructor HR"<< std::endl;

};
void HR::addEmp(Employee)
{
    std::vector < Employee > all;
};
HR::~HR()
{
    std::cout << "destructor HR"<< std::endl;
};
```

Comment: Why did you tag this C?

Comment: I'm sorry, i missclicked. Thank u for correcting.

Comment: "Employee with no methods, just constructor" <- then don't declare the destructor. And if a destructor is required, follow the rule of five. And no, The `Employee` class should not know about the `HR` class and especially not about the way objects of it's type are stored in that class.

Comment: @JHBonarius rule of five have "copy constructor" and "move constructor" rules. Should i copy or move constructor of Employee to the second class (HR) and then inside the class make container with this copied/moved constructor? Also this container should be in constructor of second class right? Sorry if i sound stupid, i'm confused.

Comment: @el_vandean_1453 `std::string` is fully compliant with the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which means your `Employee` class is automatically fully compliant as well by default, so you don’t need to add a manual destructor, copy/move constructor, or copy/move assignment to it at all, the default implementations provided by the compiler will do the right things for you. You only need to add those things when your class has resources it must manage manually, like `new`‘ed/externally allocated memory, etc.

Comment: To solve your issue, simply move all of the creation and management of the `std::vector` from `main()` to inside your `HR` class. If you are having trouble doing that, you need to [edit] your question to show the code for `HR`.  And no, you should not call `push_back()` in your `Employee` constructor.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65280618/edit) your post to show the HR code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited the post to show HR.h and HR.cpp, but its almost nothing there. I dont really know how this class should look like. Should the constructor have  this std::vector container as an argument to create it and then somehow push_back() objects into this container?

Comment: @el_vandean_1453 there are many ways you could implement this. The easiest would be to add a method to `HR` that takes an `Employee` as a parameter and pushes it as-is into the `vector`. Why is the `vector` declared as `static`, though?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I made this method you stated and edited my post. Should i now write all push_back's in this method also? Do u have a clue if should i write anything in HR constructor? It was static because in one of my "error attempts" my IDE did a hint to me to do it, its no more static.

Comment: @el_vandean_1453 you removed the `vector` from `HR` completely. Put it back, just don't make it `static`. Then do a `push_back() `inside of `addEmp()`. Then `main()` can create an `HR` object and call `addEmp()` to add `Employee` objects into it.

Comment: You need to read a book on object oriented programming (optionally specific for C++) because this trial and error thing isn't working. If this is an assignment, discuss or with your teacher or fellow students.